# How to assign default size to JSplitPane components while screen opening?

Tags: jsplitpane

Hi want to assign default height and width to jsplitpane components while opening the screen. what is the simplest way to perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found is to override setVisible() for the Frame that the splitpane is nested in and then call setDividerLocation() on the splitpane itself.

setDividerLocation() can take either an int (pixel location) or a double (proportional width/height).